# Stuffing Hash in Array behaves differently using "var" rather than :var -- why?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, variables, hash

Why do these snippets of code behave differently?  I thought they were supposed to do the same thing...

```
    foo = {}
    array = []

    foo['a'] = "1"
    foo['b'] = "2"

    array << foo

    foo['a'] = "3"
    foo['b'] = "4"

    array << foo

    output => [{"a"=>"3", "b"=>"4"}, {"a"=>"3", "b"=>"4"}]
```

This is not what I want.  Fortunately, I tried using this format, which works:

```
    foo = {}
    array = []

    foo = {
        :a => "1",
        :b => "2"
    }

    array << foo

    foo = {
        :a => "3",
        :b => "4"
    }

    array << foo

    output => [{:a=>"1", :b=>"2"}, {:a=>"3", :b=>"4"}]
```

What's going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not `"` vs. `:` — it's that you're *modifying* `foo` (`foo[...]=...`) in the first example while you're *reassigning* the variable `foo` (`foo=...`) in the second. In the first example, `foo` still refers to the same object (which is also in the array) after you put in the values 3 & 4.

For a solution, I recommend the second option (which you can use with `'`/`"` (strings) or `:` (symbols), no matter), or alternatively you can do `array << foo.clone` to push a copy of `foo` onto the array, so further modifications won't change it.

Comment: Thank you; I always forget that darned .clone method.

Answer (score 0):

In your first example, you push foo itself into the array.  When you edit foo on the next few lines, you are editing the same hash which you just pushed into the array!

In your second example, you explicitly set foo to a new hash using the '{}' operators.  So when you set the values of 'a' and 'b', you don't touch the original foo already pushed into the array.